# Can I encrypt c source code at compile time?

Tags: c, obfuscation, pack

I want to encode some part of the source code at compile time.

The goal is that calls/references to the protected function/library do not show up in disassemblers like IDA Pro or Ghidra.

Eg.:

```
void ImportantFunction() {

    ENCODE_START(134);
    ...
    Code to encode
    ...
    ENCODE_END(0);

}
```

Here, 134 is encode key.

Is this possible? Does anyone know?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As I understand the process of compiling, it takes your source code and creates a binary file that the computer to run/understand.  Would the encrypted code be code that needs to be run or is it just data code that you want to hide?

Comment: A compiled binary is just bytes, so like any bytes, it could be encrypted.  The problem is it would need to be *de*crypted to be executed.  And then once it was decrypted and executed, its internals would be visible to a debugger.

Comment: In other words, i want to pack some part of code. The encrypted code must to be run.
The purpose is to protect only a portion of the code with the packing, not the entire PE file.

Comment: It's doable, but at some point the code needs to be decrypted to run, at which point someone can see the decrypted code in a debugger.

Comment: Yeah.  Even if you did, the encryption key couldn't itself be encrypted, so it would be pretty obvious what it was by looking at the wrapper.

Comment: @erik258 Depends on if the key is embedded in the executable or in some external file.  You could use a TPM if you want to be fancy about it.

Comment: The TL;DR: Short of using some special environment (e.g. `TPM`), somebody has to give the decryption key to the program [by _whatever_ means] to decrypt the "secret" code. Once that is done, the decrypted code can be examined/copied--full stop. If you really want to "protect" some code, have the program contact a server that you control, send it data, and have the server execute the secret/protected code. It then sends back the results. This is a variation of SaaS (software as a service).

Comment: Can't I raise the pack security level? The goal is that program protect from static debugger. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: Host the sensitive code on a server that you control?

Comment: TPM is not suitable for me.
Is there any other way? Does anyone know more?

Comment: There are also tricks you can do where two processes trace each other (that way no other process can attach), but even that's not foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

> *The goal is that calls/references to the protected function/library do not show up in disassemblers like IDA Pro or Ghidra.*

Compile or hand translate the function to a custom byte code, which appears as just an array of data.

Off-the-shelf disassemblers won't know what that is.